# BigQuery load job failing on boolean data type fields from JSON

Tags: python, json, google-bigquery

I'm receiving an " Invalid data file" error when loading a NDJSON file into Google BigQuery when I include a boolean data type column.  The job runs successfully if I remove those columns from the schema and source file.   I'm using the load_table_from_uri process thru a python script, but I've also tried it in the gui and its the same issue.  The json file for the boolean fields looks correct (attached).  I've also tried both the legacy and current boolean data types (BOOL vrs BOOLEAN) What am I missing.

```
dataset_id = 'dev'  
table_id = 'DIM_EMP'  
table_ref = bqClient.dataset(dataset_id).table(table_id)

job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
job_config.schema = [
bigquery.SchemaField('personId', 'INT64'),
bigquery.SchemaField('personNumber', 'STRING'),
bigquery.SchemaField('firstName', 'STRING'),
bigquery.SchemaField('middleName', 'STRING'),
bigquery.SchemaField('lastName', 'STRING'),
bigquery.SchemaField('userName', 'STRING'),
bigquery.SchemaField('accessProfile', 'STRING'),
bigquery.SchemaField('notificationProfile', 'STRING'),
bigquery.SchemaField('preferenceProfile', 'STRING'),
bigquery.SchemaField('supervisorPersonId', 'INT64'),
bigquery.SchemaField('hireDate', 'DATE'),
bigquery.SchemaField('processEmployeeProfile', 'STRING'),
bigquery.SchemaField('logonProfile', 'STRING'),
bigquery.SchemaField('birthDate', 'DATE'),
bigquery.SchemaField('delegateProfile', 'STRING'),
**bigquery.SchemaField('isManager','BOOLEAN')
bigquery.SchemaField('isEmployee','BOOL'),**
bigquery.SchemaField('localeProfile', 'STRING')
]
job_config.write_disposition = bigquery.WriteDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE
job_config.source_format = bigquery.SourceFormat.NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON
uri = 'gs://'+project+'-stage/getPeopleDetails/DIMEMP*.ndjson'
load_job = bqClient.load_table_from_uri(
    uri,
    table_ref,
    job_config=job_config)  # API request

load_job.result()
```

[Source JSON file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Yy3o.jpg)

Comment: Your json file looks like Python print output. JSON booleans are false/true (lowercase) but I see False/True in the file. Also strings should be double-quoted not single-quote.

Comment: Thanks,  the quotes dont seem to be an issue, but I'll change then anyway.   The boolean comes directly from another json.load command from another API call so I was not expecting that Id have to lower case it, but I'll give it a try!

Comment: Ok,  the fix was to convert the JSON boolean to a string in my source to just 'true' or 'false' and then big query imported it back to a boolean data type without issue.

Comment: I posted your answer as community wiki to help others who may run into the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

For loading NDJSON file into BigQuery, the boolean values true and false should be placed between quotation marks. If a column only contains ‘true’ or ‘false’, BigQuery will automatically set its type to Boolean.